# How to show Picker items according to localization language in Xamarin.Forms xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker, itemsource

A standard way to create a picker with xaml is the following.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource

```
<Picker x:Name="picker"
        Title="Select a monkey"
        TitleColor="Red">
  <Picker.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
      <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
      <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
      <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
    </x:Array>
  </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

Instead of using hardcode text as "Baboon", "Capuchin Monkey", etc. I want to use localization strings as extension markup (x:Static).

[Use of static markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCA8f.png)

[Default language resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwDJN.png)

[Spanish language resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG3Pt.png)

How can I achive that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A workaround is add the items directly to the picker when the View is instantiated.

1-) Normal localization resources,

[default language "en-US"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kieYo.png)

[English resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jNpD.png)

[Spanish resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgHFd.png)

2-) [Declare a basic picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJVNW.png)

3-) [Populate the picker in the corresponding view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8s9G.png)

Result:

[English](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQWVf.jpg)

[Spanish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFlL9.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can bind `.resx` to ViewModel , then bind ViewModel for `Picker` to achieve that .

Create two `.resx` file , one is for english language.

```
<data name="Baboon" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Baboon</value>
</data>
<data name="Blue" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Blue Monkey</value>
</data>
<data name="Capuchin" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Capuchin Monkey</value>
</data>
<data name="Golden" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Golden Lion Tamarin</value>
</data>
<data name="Howler" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Howler Monkey</value>
</data>
<data name="Japanese" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Japanese Monkey</value>
</data>
<data name="Squirrel" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Squirrel Monkey</value>
</data>
```

Another is for spanish language

```
<data name="Baboon" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Babuino</value>
</data>
<data name="Blue" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Mono azul</value>
</data>
<data name="Capuchin" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Mono capuchino</value>
</data>
<data name="Golden" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Tamarin León Dorado</value>
</data>
<data name="Howler" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Mono aullador</value>
</data>
<data name="Japanese" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Mono japonés</value>
</data>
<data name="Squirrel" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Mono ardilla</value>
</data>
```

Create **Monkey** class :

```
public class Monkey
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

Create **MonkeyModel** class:

```
public class MonkeyModel
{
    public List<Monkey> Monkeys { set; get; }
    public MonkeyModel()
    {
        Monkeys = new List<Monkey>();
        Monkeys.Add(new Monkey() { Name = AppResources.Blue });
        Monkeys.Add(new Monkey() { Name = AppResources.Capuchin });
        Monkeys.Add(new Monkey() { Name = AppResources.Baboon });
        Monkeys.Add(new Monkey() { Name = AppResources.Squirrel });
        Monkeys.Add(new Monkey() { Name = AppResources.Golden });
        Monkeys.Add(new Monkey() { Name = AppResources.Howler });
        Monkeys.Add(new Monkey() { Name = AppResources.Japanese });
    }
}
```

Now in **Xaml** Picker bind data :

```
<Picker x:Name="picker"
        Title="Select a monkey"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
        TitleColor="Red" />
```

Binding Context in Content Page :

```
MonkeyModel monkeyModel = new MonkeyModel();

picker.ItemsSource = monkeyModel.Monkeys;
```

The effect in spanish language setting :

[image]

Default lauguage setting :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it has a lot of sense.

Before read your answer I've achieved this in a simple way. Just I've added directly the items (adding the default resource string) to the picker when the View is instantiated.

Comment: @humbertropolis Okey , if answer be helpful ,remmeber to vote it up :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Junior Jiang - MSFT's answer pretty much covers it, if you want to use it with a view model binding.

However, you can still use it directly into the XAML with [Localize Text in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=macos#localize-text-in-xamarinforms).

Basically, you would have again 2 or more resource files with translations and you can invoke the translated strings directly in the XAML like so:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:LocalizationDemo.Resx">
    <Label Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.NotesLabel}" />
    <Entry Placeholder="{x:Static resources:AppResources.NotesPlaceholder}" />
    <Button Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.AddButton}" />
</ContentPage>
```